# best way to store 1:1 user relationships in relational database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

What is the best way to store user relationships, e.g. friendships, that must be bidirectional (you're my friend, thus I'm your friend) in a rel. database, e.g. MYSql?

I can think of two ways:

1. Everytime a user friends another user, I'd add two rows to a database, row A consisting of the user id of the innitiating user followed by the UID of the accepting user in the next column. Row B would be the reverse.
2. You'd only add one row, UID(initiating user) followed by UID(accepting user); and then just search through both columns when trying to figure out whether user 1 is a friend of user 2.

Surely there is something better?

Comment: sounds like you have the design right on.  What your refering to is an association between two tables to create a 0..1 or many between each table and the association table.  In the end what it nets is a many to many.  But I must say your right on with handling it this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have a link table for friends, or whatever, with 2 columns both being PK's, and both being FK's to the User table.

Both columns would be the UID, and you would have two rows per friend relationship (A,B and B,A).  As long as both columns are PK's, it should still be in normal format (although others are free to correct me on this)

Its a little more complex of a query, but nothing that can't be abstracted away by a  stored procedure or some business logic, and its in Normal Format, which is usually nice to have.

Comment: Just remember that in MySQL the default engine MyISAM does not support foreign keys, switch to InnoDB.

Comment: True enough, but if you absolutely had to use MyISAM, you could get away with these not being actual FK's, but it could affect your data integrity and normalization, stick with InnoDB

Comment: I would go with this system as well as it greatly simplifies the select queries for looking up friends, especially when you need to join against this table. However you should use transactions and stored procedures to make sure both rows are always inserted and deleted together (you do **not** want to accidentally delete one of the two rows).

Answer (score 5):

You could check which of the two user_id's is the lowest and store them in a specific order. This way you don't need double rows for one friendship and still keep your queries simple.

user_id_low | user_id_high

a simple query to check if you're already friends with someone would be:

```
<?php
$my_id = 2999;
$friend_id = 500;

$lowest = min($my_id, $friend_id);
$highest= max($my_id, $friend_id);

query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id_low=$lowest AND user_id_high=$highest");
?>
```

Or you could find the lowest/higest userid using mysql

```
<?php
query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id_low=LEAST($my_id, $friend_id) AND user_id_high=GREATEST($my_id, $friend_id)");
?>
```

And to get all your friends id's

```
<?php

query("SELECT IF(user_id_low=$my_id,user_id_high,user_id_low) AS friend_id FROM friends WHERE $my_id IN (user_id_low, user_id_high)");

?>
```

Comment: after looking at this for half a minute and just feeling i would come up with a good reason why this should not be used. But no, i didn't. This is not a bad solution - quite elegant actually :) actually this also supports a system where you could arrange a group of for example 100 friends group, just putting them all in an asc/desc order

Answer (score 4):

Using double rows, while it creates extra data, will greatly simplify your queries and allow you to index smartly. I also remember seeing info on Twitter's custom MySQL solution wherein they used an additional field (friend #, basically) to do automatic limiting and paging. It seems pretty smooth:
https://blog.twitter.com/2010/introducing-flockdb

Answer (score -6):

Use a key value store, such as Cassandra for example.

Comment: The request was specifically regarding a MySQL solution.