# How can I show mutual relation between two users in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show relation between two users. I want to insert only one row to `Relations` table *(see structure below)*. But my script is showing that user B is friend of himself - that's not right.

This is a structure of my database *(with examples)*:

```
Users
id|email|password|name|pic_url|friend_count
1 |a@.. |aaaaaaaa|A   |http...|1
2 |b@...|bbbbbbbb|B   |http...|0

Relations
id|user_id|friend_id|status(0 and 1)
1 |1      |2        |1(if accepted)
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's my query:

```
SELECT Relations.friend_id, Users.name,Users.email,Users.pic_url FROM Relations
INNER JOIN Users
ON Relations.friend_id = Users.id

WHERE  Relations.user_id = $user_id
OR Relations.friend_id = $user_id
AND Relations.status = 1
```

Comment: you mean to say you are just able to show the friendlist one way only ?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and what you want inserted into the database.

Comment: Yes but how to do it  is my table wrong of the query please help me with this

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check sir

Comment: You're saying that _"B is in friend list of A but A is not in the list of B"_ - is that what you want or it's wrong?

Comment: yes sir exactly thats what i am saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to insert two rows into `Relations` table.

```
id|user_id|friend_id|status(0 and 1)
1 |1      |2        |1(if accepted)
2 |2      |1        |1(if accepted)
```

For example, user A send friend request to B. Until B accept this request, the `status` of both rows would be `0`.

Query for accepting: (user B)

```
UPDATE Relations SET status=1 WHERE (user_id=$user_id AND friend_id=$friend_id) OR (user_id=$friend_id AND friend_id=$user_id)
```

Query for selecting:

```
SELECT Relations.friend_id, Users.name, Users.email, Users.pic_url FROM Relations
    INNER JOIN Users
    ON Relations.friend_id = Users.id

    WHERE Relations.user_id = $user_id
    AND Relations.status = 1
```

---

**Update:** If you really want to insert only one row, you would need to execute two queries - the one for the friends user B added and another one for the friends that has added User B to their friend list.

```
SELECT Relations.friend_id, Users.name, Users.email, Users.pic_url FROM Relations
    INNER JOIN Users
    ON Relations.friend_id = Users.id

    WHERE Relations.user_id = $user_id
    AND Relations.status = 1

SELECT Relations.user_id, Users.name, Users.email, Users.pic_url FROM Relations
    INNER JOIN Users
    ON Relations.user_id = Users.id

    WHERE Relations.friend_id = $user_id
    AND Relations.status = 1
```

Your problem is that you're selecting friend_id which means that if you execute your query as user B, the `friend_id` would be 2 - user B. *(see your table example)*

You should take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2909558) for more information about performance.

Comment: thank you for your efforts sir but i am about in more concerned that will be the right way? if i have many many of tables wouldnt it be slow

Comment: @emanual Tell me, how many users do you have? If it's more than one hundred thousand, my solution probably wouldn't be the best.

Comment: i think there wouldnt be probably more than one hundred thousands i think but would break the normalization where as example is good too so asking you about these things as i think you know more than me

Comment: @emanual If you really want to insert only one row, you would need to execute two queries - see my updated answer.

Comment: but making two queries would solve one problem and makes another problem too how to put the object in loop i was putting 1st object to loop now how to put ur second query in loop?

Comment: @emanual I can't tell you that until I see your loop, but as you have two queries, you should have two loops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83623/discussion-between-emanual-and-genhis).